# Accessing Properties.Resources/Settings within partial subclasses of Application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, embedded-resource

I'm trying to access an icon from my resources and it's not available.   It seems to be available in a window.  How can I access them?

```
namespace My_Application
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            /* Compile error "'System.Collections.IDictionary' does not contain a definition for 'Resources'…" */
            Properties.Resources.Application; 

            base.OnStartup(e);
        }
    }
```

This one works!  It's in a Window Class

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
             /* Available */
             Properties.Resources.Application;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried resequencing it to after the call to `base.OnStartup`?

Comment: Yes, The error I get is


Error 1 'System.Collections.IDictionary' does not contain a definition for 'Resources' and no extension method 'Resources' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.IDictionary' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Ah, OK. Try fully referencing it with your project namespace, `My_Application.`. I don't rightly know why that makes a difference, but it seems to.

Answer (score 1):

So for some reason within App.xaml.cs, it's necessary to disambiguate using the project namespace whenever using automatic Settings or Resources classes. `using` directives and assembly references are verified to be irrelevant.